# Can you use class template argument deduction when the class is template parameter of another template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I tried to write code like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std::string_literals;
int main(){
    std::vector v{1,2,3};
    std::pair p{1,"a"s};
    //std::vector<std::pair> vp{{1,"a"s}, {2, "b"s},{3,"c"s}};  // ERROR
}
```

But it gives compile error in the line where pair is a template parameter of vector.

Is there a way to get class template deduction to work here or do I need to specify template parameters for pair?

Comment: @PiotrNycz tnx, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported at the moment. From [[dcl.type.class.deduct]p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct#2):

> A placeholder for a deduced class type can also [in variable declarations too as type] be used in the *type-specifier-seq* in the *new-type-id* or *type-id* of a *new-expression*, or as the *simple-type-specifier* in an explicit type conversion (functional notation). **A placeholder for a deduced class type shall not appear in any other context.**

As you can see from the sentence I highlighted, because your use does not match any of the places mentioned above, your code is ill-formed.

You could do something like this:

```
std::vector vp{std::pair{1, "a"s}, {2, "b"s}, {3, "c"s}};
```

Comment: I do not understand the standard quote, but I assume you do,and that it does say what you say so accepting. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I'm gonna "translate" it: "A template name without the template argument list can also be used in a `new` expression (as the type), or as the type in an explicit type conversion (functional notation). Such a template name cannot appear in any other context."